# How to forward typedef'd struct in .h

Tags: c, typedef, forward-declaration

I have
Preprocessor.h

```
#define MAX_FILES 15

struct Preprocessor {
    FILE fileVector[MAX_FILES];
    int currentFile;
};

typedef struct Preprocessor Prepro;

void Prepro_init(Prepro* p) {
    (*p).currentFile = 0;
}
```

I realized then that I had to separate declarations from definitions. So I created Preprocessor.c:

```
#define MAX_FILES 15

struct Preprocessor {
    FILE fileVector[MAX_FILES];
    int currentFile;
};

typedef struct Preprocessor Prepro;
```

And Preprocessor.h is now:

```
void Prepro_init(Prepro* p) {
    (*p).currentFile = 0;
}
```

That obviously, doesn't work because Pr..h doesn't know Prepro type. I already tried several combinations, none of them worked. I can't find the solution.

Comment: no forward-declaration here..

Comment: Note that, if you use pointers to `struct`s a lot, you'll find the `->` operator quite useful. `(*p).currentFile` can be written as `p->currentFile`.

Comment: This is C. I'm almost sure you can't do that in C.

Comment: @Erandros No, the `->` operator is very much valid in C as well as C++

Comment: You're right, -> is valid in C.

Comment: Do not use `typedef struct Preprocessor Prepro`, you may want to create a pointer to `prepro` somewhere without including this header (since including more headers increases compile time exponentially) and make a forward declaration somewhere else. Use a name for the `struct` and `typedef` that are clear and that you know the name for both as soon as you know one of them. Simplest way would be using the same name for both.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Move the `typedef struct Preprocessor Prepro;` to the header the file and the definition in the c file along with the Prepro_init definition. This is will forward declare it for you with no issues.

Preprocessor.h

```
#ifndef _PREPROCESSOR_H_
#define _PREPROCESSOR_H_

#define MAX_FILES 15

typedef struct Preprocessor Prepro;

void Prepro_init(Prepro* p);

#endif
```

Preprocessor.c

```
#include "Preprocessor.h"

#include <stdio.h>

struct Preprocessor {
    FILE fileVector[MAX_FILES];
    int currentFile;
};

void Prepro_init(Prepro* p) {
    (*p).currentFile = 0;
}
```

Comment: Preprocessor may be a poor name choice but thats up to you :) Also `FILE` is often referenced with a pointer, `FILE *`

Comment: I'd put the actual `struct` definition in another header so you could split your implementation into different source files as well. That'd make it easier to get the function you want.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: Maybe he wants it to be an opaque type

Comment: OK for .h file, but now, the c file doesn't know what Prepro is.

Comment: It needs to be included either explicitly as in my example or through some precompiled header.

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried with the exact same code you posted. Compiler says: "Field 'currentFile' could not be resolved". I think that Prepro type is not resolved when compiling c file.

Comment: @Erandros : the way it's set up here, you can not access the `currentFile` member (or any member for that matter) outside of the Preprocessor.c file. If you need to be able to do that, you'll need to put the definition for `struct Preprocessor` in the header file, and include the header file wherever you want to use it.

Comment: No, the way it's set up here, you cannot access currentFile INSIDE of Preprocessor.c, because it won't compile, because compiler can't resolve Prepro in c file (I think).

Comment: @Praetorian - That's still possible. I like to use an internal header that defines `struct`s for implementation files, and an external header that just provides an opaqje declaration.

Comment: @Erandros : it will see the typedef for `Prepro`, because of the `#include "Preprocessor.h"` at the top. Make sure that you have the exact files shown here, and that you name them exactly as indicated.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to hide the definition of `Preprocessor`, you can simply put this in the header file :

```
struct Preprocessor;
typedef struct Preprocessor Prepro;
```

But more generally, you'll probably also need the `Preprocessor` definition in the header file, to allow other code to actually use it.

Comment: The first line is unnecessary, as the second will also declare that `struct Preprocessor` exists without defining it.

Comment: @Chris : I know, but thought it'd make things clearer by explicitly showing the forward declaration.

Comment: You should also mention that the only possible uses of the Prepro type are through pointers. The definition of the type will then go in the .c file and the implementation will be the only to know the internals of Prepro.

Comment: Great answer. The "but more generally, you'll probably also need the definition in the header file" bit is a little overstated... Often all you need in a header is just a pointer to the struct, in which case your 2-line solution (or even Chris's 1-line variant) works great.

Answer (score 1):

You have put in `.c` what should be in `.h`, and vice versa. `Prepro_init` must be in `.c` file, and that file must `#include "Preprocessor.h"`.

Answer (score 0):

YAS:Yet Another Solution.

Preprocessor.h

```
<some code>
    void Prepro_init(Prepro* p) {
        (*p).currentFile = 0;
    }
<some code>
```

Preprocessor.c

```
#define MAX_FILES 15

struct Preprocessor {
    FILE fileVector[MAX_FILES];
    int currentFile;
};
typedef struct Preprocessor Prepro;

#include "Preprocessor.h"      //include after defining your structure.

         <some code> 
        {
              struct Prepro p;
              Prepro_init(p);
     <some code> 
          .... using p.currentFile.....
          .....using other members....
     <some code> 
        }
           <some code>
```

Now it will work. I think this is your requirement. Hope it helps.

**Drawback:** 
  The members of the structure Preprocessor, must be predetermined. i.e the header file uses the member currentFile. So, c file which includes Preprocessor.h must have a structure which is typedefined as Prepro and that structure must include a member currentFile.(in this case).

The same problem I had a year before, while writting a header file  to display a users Avl tree in a graphical tree format.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you follow Linus[1], and do not use typedef struct.

## If you are in control over the library:

Include file

```
struct Foo;

int foo_get_n(const struct Foo *bar);
```

In implementation file

```
struct Foo
{int n;};

int foo_get_n(const struct Foo *bar)
{return bar->n;}
```

## If you are not in control over the library:

Ask the maintainer to remove these polluting typedefs from the include files.

## Summary

Do not use typedef struct.

[1] http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/typedefs.html

Answer (score -4):

Swap `.h` and `.c` file. Include header in `.c`.

Also refer to a book about declarations, definitions and what header files do.

Comment: Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: Any decent book will do, stroustrup / meyers / sutter.

Comment: Those are C++ books, are you sure it will be the same for C? C++ is a lot easier to forward.