# C forward declaration for typedef struct

Tags: c, struct, typedef, forward-declaration

I'm trying to forward declare typedef struct wheels.

```
typedef struct wheels wheels;

typedef struct car {
  float topSpeed;
  wheels w;
} car;

typedef struct wheels {
  int frontWheels;
  int backWheels;
} wheels; 

int main() {
  car c = {
    .topSpeed = 255.0,
    .w = {
      .frontWheels = 2,
      .backWheels = 2,
    }
  };

  return 0; 
}
```

This gives me the following errors:

> error: field ‘w’ has incomplete type wheels w;
>
> error: field name not in record or union initializer .frontWheels = 2
>
> error: field name not in record or union initializer .backWheels = 2

I know I can move the entire typedef struct wheels above the typedef struct car and it would work.

How do I forward declare struct wheels correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to forward typedef'd struct in .h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259238/how-to-forward-typedefd-struct-in-h)

Comment: For the definition of a variable of a structure *object* you need the full definition of the structure (because the compiler needs to know its size). Forward declarations are very useful for *pointers* to structures, since then the compiler only needs to know the size of the pointer and not the whole structure.

Comment: You can forward declare a struct but you cannot use a forward-declared struct for declaring variables (or other struct members). Why do you need to forward-declare it? It doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: And in this case, why can't the definition of `struct wheels` come before `struct car`? The `wheels` structure doesn't depend on `car` in any way, so it can easily be moved.

Comment: For this specific case, moving doesn't make a difference. I wanted to know if it's possible at all in C to have such forward declarations.

Comment: OT:  variable (and parameter) names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  Names like `w` are meaningless, even in the current context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the relevant sections from the C standard (emphasis added):

§6.2.5p1

> At various points within a translation unit an object type may be
>   incomplete (lacking sufficient information to determine the size of
>   objects of that type) or complete (having sufficient information).

§6.7.2p3

> A structure or union **shall not contain a member with incomplete** or
>   function **type** (hence, a structure shall not contain an instance of
>   itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance of itself), except
>   that the last member of a structure with more than one named member
>   may have incomplete array type; such a structure (and any union
>   containing, possibly recursively, a member that is such a structure)
>   shall not be a member of a structure or an element of an array.

The first `typedef` declares an incomplete type called `wheels`. The `car` structure uses that incomplete type as a member. That's explicitly forbidden by the standard.

That's what the first error message is telling you. The other two error messages are just noise. They are the result of the fact that the compiler did not have sufficient information to complete the `car` structure.

As mentioned in the other answer, one of the uses of incomplete types is to declare pointers. For example, a node in a linked list where the structure contains a pointer to itself:

```
typedef struct node Node;   // struct node and Node are incomplete types here

struct node
{
    int value;
    Node *next;             // using an incomplete type to declare a pointer
};                          // struct node and Node are complete from here forward
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only have the pointer to the incomplete forward defined structure or union